# XCode MAC Compiling Error

Tags: c++, xcode

I am using Xcode and I can't compile the program. This error appears:ld: 10 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Comment: Two source files using the same name variable.

Comment: @pkc456 Thanks for the reply. but I don't have same name variable.. but one of the classes is a composition in the other. is it the cause.

Comment: Share the screenshot of error. Composition will not the root cause.

Comment: Thank you @pkc456 i found the problem you were right I included a .cpp file to the other class which caused the redefinition of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have #imported a .m file by mistake somewhere in your page. Make sure this case should not be happened .